# Running Drools on GraalVM

Tags: drools

We have a service that uses Drools quite heavily. Would like to improve the performance by running it on GraalVM.

Is it possible to run Drools on GraalVM without using Kogito?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm one of the Drools developers

It's definitely possible, as you've already notice, we do indeed support native image compilation with our Quarkus backend, but it'll require you to write you some code, there's no such possibility in the current codebase.

Please note that only the executable model will be supported with the static component injection (the `drools-core-static` module in Kogito)

Is there a reason why you don't want to use Kogito though? We are really interested. Please join [our community channels](https://blog.kie.org/2020/04/new-community-channels-on-zulip-chat.html) or the mailing list if you want to share your feedbacks, as SO is not the best platform for it.

Thanks for your support

Comment: Thanks. Will get in touch.